# It's possible return the same component with new data?

Tags: angular

I have a component for example

```
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
Input() bar : string;
...
template: '<div> {{bar}}' 
}
```

Is it possible to recharge this component from there with new data?

Something like this

```
recallComponents(DataTableComponent, "foo_1");
recallComponents(DataTableComponent, "foo_2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at implementing an [observable](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html) for the data which is going to change.

> Observables open up a continuous channel of communication in which multiple values of data can be emitted over time. From this we get a pattern of dealing with data by using array-like operations to parse, modify and maintain data.
>   https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/

For example:

```
let subscription = this.data.subscribe(
    value => this.values.push(value), // on change
    error => this.anyErrors = true, // on error
    () => this.finished = true // on complete
);
```

Here is a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SA25mG?p=preview) which showcases an example of how you can use them in your project..

---

Also Note:

> [a] Router may not recreate the component when navigating to the same component. In this case the parameter may change without the component being recreated. https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html